# Convert Map<String, Object> to List<List<String>>

Tags: java

I have the following object:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> object;
```

When I serialized it I got this:

```
{
    "0" : { "0" : "str1", "1" : "str2", ... },
    "1" : { "0" : "str1", "1" : "str2", ... },
    ...
}
```

The question is: how can I convert this `Map` to `List<List<String>>`?

Here is my current solution:

```
List<List<String>> listlist;
...
for (Map<String, String> mss : object.values()) {
    List<String> list = ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : mss.values) {
        list.add(s);
    }
    listlist.add(list);
}
```

The obvious solution is to traverse `Map` and extract values, but is there any tricky way?

Comment: What's the actual type of `Object` values? Is that other `Map` objects?

Comment: Can you type the expected serialized output ?

Comment: A) please clarify your requirements. Do you just want the values of each map entry? B) consider adding your own trials. Questions asking "please do the work for me" don't fly well here, most of the time.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over each one, there is no other way ,but you can it using `Streams` too, you can find this clearer :

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> object;
List<List<String>> list = object.values().stream().map(m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values))
                                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```